# enumerate gridlines on the right hand side of each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

I have the following situation:
[image]

Since the plot is busy, and I need to stack facets horizontally, I'd like to add the gridline number (1, 2, 3... from top to bottom) on the right hand side of each facet as a small annotation.

Example:

```
df -> structure(list(x = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C"), y = c(-0.0266895396994591, 1.2629902531844, 
-0.197547366036169, -0.334884614303217, -1.31341546345431, 
0.679653721629223, 
0.646719367666199, 0.5724201029025, -0.518199049316855, 
0.720858806355891, 
-0.752050452401081, 0.573150406892228)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = 
c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and the code to produce the plot is

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
     geom_boxplot() +
     coord_flip()
```

So I'd like to enumerate the three major grid lines with 1,2,3 at the right hand side

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please share some code and reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `scale_x_discrete` and add the `labels` you want with the right `position` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = as.character(c(1:3)),
                   position = "top")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>